# invalid elf header error for .so file

Tags: python, linux, import

I'm trying to run a script in python, and I'm getting an "invalid elf header" error. I have a series of scripts that call one another, I'll go ahead and include those as well:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras-03-03/python")
from python_utilities import GRASTestor
```

which calls GRASTestor.py

```
from BaseTestor import BaseTestor
import numpy as np
import hepunit as unit
from gdml_writer import gdml_writer 
from GDMLGeometryBuilder import GDMLGeometryBuilder
from GRASMacroBuilder import GRASMacroBuilder,GRASRMCMacroBuilder
from Plotters import Plotter
import os
import sys
import SpenvisCSVFileHandler
```

which calls SpenvisCSVFileHandler.py

```
import  string
import Spenvis.so
import os
from numpy import *
```

which is where we get our error, specifically with the line "import Spenvis.so"

```
/home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "perform_gras_rmc_tests.py", line 6, in <module>
    from python_utilities import GRASTestor
  File "/home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities/GRASTestor.py", line 19, in <module>
    import SpenvisCSVFileHandler
  File "/home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities/SpenvisCSVFileHandler.py", line 8, in <module>
    import Spenvis.so
ImportError: /home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities/Spenvis.so: invalid ELF header
```

And I'm not certain why it's not working. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. Upon looking at the file architecture, it appears the file Spenvis.so is mac specific for some reason. Just need to get the correct file, then.